# Deploying a web app that has only one user

Tags: node.js

How would I go about deploying a web app intended for only a single user (myself)? I feel like making a login that only accepts 1 user is the wrong method and also easy to hack? Would it be a good idea to make it only accessible from a certain IP? Please advise! Thank you. Backend will be using nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would program the back-end the *proper* way. This involves generalizing the entire implementation so that any **hypothetical** user with the correct password could use your login system. You could still authorize and authenticate the application so that when anybody else tries to log in, you automatically decline their request. If you are concerned about security, ensure that you are using SSL, basic encryption, hash passwords and, most importantly, **do not use your own authorization library**. It is far more secure if you use OAuth instead of using an IP, for example. Last, but definitely not least, make it as hard as you can for hackers to steal your data in the **client side**. This way, you also learn a lot of things that might come in handy in the near future.